# Why is my website not showing the left side in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css

www.regretproject.org is my site. I'm having a p problem in which the menu on the left side is cut off entirely on Android, and half way on mobile Safari. Any tricks to force it to see the whole thing?
www.regretproject.org/css/style.css for the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: hey @iambriansreed... can you explain what this all means? thanks!

Comment: A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3Cmeta+content%3D'width%3Ddevice-width%3B+initial-scale%3D1.0%3B+maximum-scale%3D1.0%3B+user-scalable%3D0%3B'+name%3D'viewport'+%2F%3E%3Cmeta+name%3D%22viewport%22+content%3D%22width%3Ddevice-width%22+%2F%3E) could tell you more than I ever could.

Answer (score 1):

Well... you're positioning your content to the right...

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1024px;
    right: 0%;
    height: 500px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

... why do you do this? Is there a special purpose this position serves? I would recommend just centering your content instead of doing absolute positioning:

```
#container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I wanted the text of the title to be up against the background a certain way, but it looks fine and functionality comes first for now. Thank you!